# Brother 5980CN updating recent firmware

Tags: printing, printer

How to update a firmware when the current one is already a recent one?
I need to do that in order to change language.

I bought a Brother 5890CN printer. Unfortunately, it has only Scandinavia languages enabled. I tried unsuccessfully to update the firmware with recent english image. Unfortunately, the update software tells that I have recent version of firmware and quits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the f/w there appears to be a way to just change the language:

1. Turn off the machine
2. Hold in the MENU button.
3. Turn on the machine while holding the menu button
4. Maintenance should come up onscreen and the lights should flash.
5. Key in the numbers 74 and press Mono Start button.
6. Key in 0004 and press Mono Start button.
7. "MAINTENANCE" appears again on the display.
8. Key in 99 at the maintenance prompt to exit to the date and time
   It should be now in English

http://www.fixya.com/support/t4641262-change_brother_mfc_5890cn_language